# Generalization Bounds

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability, upper-lower-bounds, error-function

Given the loss function $L(\hat{y},y)$

the generalization error is defined as
$$R(h) = \underset{(x,y)\sim D}{\mathrm{E}}[L(h(x),y)]$$

the empirical error is defined as
$$\hat R(h) = \frac{1}{m}\underset{i=1}{\sum^{m}}[L(h(x_i),y_i)]$$

Bayes Error
$$R^* = \underset{\substack{h\\h\:measurable}}{\mathrm{inf}} R(h)$$

The difference between the error of a hypothesis $h \in H$ and the Bayes error can be decomposed as:
$$R(h) - R^* = R(h) - R(h^*) + R(h^*) - R^*$$
where $h^*$ is a hypothesis in H with minimal error, or a $best-in-class$ $hypothesis$

finding hypothesis $h \in H$ minimizing empirical error
$$h = \underset{h \in H}{argmin} \hat R(h)  $$

Bound on estimation error for hypothesis $h_0$ is given by
\begin{align*}
R(h_0) - R(h^*) &= R(h_0) - \hat R(h_0) + \hat R(h_0) - R(h^*)\\
&\leq R(h_0) - \hat R(h_0) + \hat R(h_0) - R(h^*)\\
&\leq \underset {h\in H}{\sup}|R(h) - \hat R(h)|
\end{align*}

I am reading about generalization bound from a power point, and couldn't understand how we get the third inequality from the second inequality. The prrof above leads to the statement below, and I couldn't make sense of it either.

$$Pr \begin{bmatrix} \underset{h\in H}{sup} R(h) - \hat R(h) > \epsilon \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Is this from Mohri's machine learning class?

Comment: Not from his class, but it's from his book the Foundations of Machine Learning which is being used in my Machine Learnin Theory class

Comment: I took the class with him before, and I'll write an answer to you if I'm free. I'm trying to recall what he taught in his class

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help